# Structs with FieldOffsetValueAttribute

Tags: c#, attributes, struct

I am currently doing some reading on structs and came across an example of structs being used with attributes. In the example the struct attribute being used is `[FieldOffset(0)]` which it says makes sure the fields are stored in the same piece of memory.

What is the advantage(s) or disadvantage(s) of this?
Also why would one want to use `FieldOffsetAttribute` to put the fields in different parts of memory?

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx: `This sort of control over struct layout is useful when using platform invocation.`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yes but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used to control the exact offset in memory of the members of the struct. It's sometimes used in C# when you want to represent a native (C++) struct in the context of a [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) call.

In C# there is no things such as structs unions, so you have to use `FieldOffsetValueAttribute`.

I recommend you to read [the following article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this trick used somewhere, which will change the underlying type of the array, from uint to int, **without copying** the elements of the array:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ArrayTypeChanger
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int[] ArrayOfInts;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint[] ArrayOfUInts;
}
```

and somewhere a type-changing method:

```
public static int[] ChangeArayType(uint[] input)
{
    return new ArrayTypeChanger { ArrayOfUInts = input }.ArrayOfInts;
}
```

No memory is copied, which should make it very fast. Of course, it only works if the types have the same size (sizeof(uint) == sizeof(int)).
Not sure MS recommends this...

Other methods of changing the type of such an array (like Marshal.Copy()) envolve some sort of memory copy and that can be a problem with large arrays.